# How to align elements in footer correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

[image: My view]

How do i center/align these columns correctly. Im using React with the React-Bootstrap lib.

This is my js for the footer component.

```js
<kbd>import { Container, ListGroup } from "react-bootstrap";

const ContainedFooterElement= () => {
   return (
   <Container>
     <footer className="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-dark text-white">
         <div className="footer-content">
            <ListGroup className="row px-5 list-unstyled">
               <h4>Social's</h4>
               <li>Facebook Icon</li>
               <li>Instagram Icon</li>
               <li>Twitter Icon</li>
               <li>Any Icon etc</li>

               <h4>Flowers4Sale.com</h4>
               <li>Our Selection</li>
               <li>View Other Locations</li>
               <li>Twitter Icon</li>
               <li>Any Icon etc</li>

               <h4>Community</h4>
               <li>Forum</li>
               <li>Email Us</li>
            </ListGroup>
            <br />
         </div>
         <div className="footer-bottom">
            <p className="text-xs-center mx-auto px-5 ">
              &copy;{new Date().getFullYear()} Portland: Flowers4Sale-All Rights Reserved.
            </p>
         </div>
     </footer>
   </Container>
   );
}

export default ContainedFooterElement;
```

Any help is much appreciated. this just stumps me right now.

I tried putting my li tags in  and now I'm stumped. I tried making each li a <ListGroup.Item> but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `text-center` like this:

```
<ListGroup className="row px-5 list-unstyled text-center">
  ....        
</ListGroup>
<p className="text-center mx-auto px-5 ">
  ....        
</p>
```